# Python: how convert values in column to one encoding

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have dataframe and I try to build graphics using `graphviz`. But I get an error

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte
```

Problems is that data in some column are different.

```
search_term
кости русский сериал стс 1 сезон 6 серия  
мультики про машинки  
пепа  
витамин d3 купить в челябинске  
скачать герои меча и магии 4 оригинал
```

next `search_terms = df['search_term'].values.tolist()`
when I use `chardet.detect(search_terms[i])` I get `'encoding': 'ascii', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'encoding': 'windows-1252'`
How can I convert it to one encoding?

Comment: does `df['search_term'].str.decode('ascii')` work?

Comment: @EdChum this string return `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @EdChum also I try `utf-8` and it return the same `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: You can try `your_string.encode('utf-8')`. This always worked for me